# How to convert the particular item in the filebeat message to lowercase using elastic search processor

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, devops, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5

I am simulating the below code in elastic search, how to convert the **event.action** in the below code from Query to **lowercase "query"** as expected in the output.

The below simulation done in the elastic devtools console:

```
POST /_ingest/pipeline/_simulate
{
  "pipeline" :
  {
    "description": "_description",
    "processors": [
      {
        "dissect": {
          "field" : "message",
          "pattern" : "%{@timestamp}\t%{->} %{process.thread.id} %{event.action}\t%{message}"
        },
        "set": {
          "field": "event.category",
          "value": "database"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "docs": [
    {
      "_index": "index",
      "_id": "id",
      "_source": {
        "message": "2020-10-22T20:28:26.267397Z\t   9 Query\tset session"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**Expected output**

```
{
  "docs" : [
    {
      "doc" : {
        "_index" : "index",
        "_id" : "id",
        "_source" : {
          "process" : {
            "thread" : {
              "id" : "9"
            }
          },
          "@timestamp" : "2020-10-22T20:28:26.267397Z",
          "message" : "set session",
          "event" : {
            "category" : "database",
            "action" : "query"
          }
        },
        "_ingest" : {
          "timestamp" : "2022-08-17T09:27:34.587465824Z"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I have updated my answer. please check and accept it, if it helps you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [lowercase processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/lowercase-processor.html) in same ingest pipeline as shown below:

```json
{
    "pipeline": {
        "description": "_description",
        "processors": [
            {
                "dissect": {
                    "field": "message",
                    "pattern": "%{@timestamp}\t%{->} %{process.thread.id} %{event.action}\t%{message}"
                }
            },
            {
                "set": {
                    "field": "event.category",
                    "value": "database"
                }
            },
            {
                "lowercase": {
                    "field": "event.action"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "docs": [
        {
            "_index": "index",
            "_id": "id",
            "_source": {
                "message": "2020-10-22T20:28:26.267397Z\t   9 Query\tset session"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```